# The simplest way to work with texts in grease pencil

Tags: grease-pencil, text-object

I am using v3.1.2
I am trying to make a 3-minute long animation with Grease Pencil.
But the text job is a pain. I just want a plain text with my drawing...
Would you tell me your best practice for text with GP?

Here are what I have tried.

Firstly, I tried to work with the plain text object as it is with my grease pencil object.
But I can't select and adjust keyframe for grease pencil object and text object at the same time. Because text object only appears in timeline when grease pencil object only appear on dope sheet. (FYI, I work on extreme keyframes first and then adjusting them with proper inbetweens, you know)

Secondly, So I tried to convert the text object into a grease pencil object. But, as you know, an enclosed part of a character needs a touch to be look properly. Otherwise, it looks clogged.
It's a lot of work for dozens of lines to 'Go into Edit mode, select all the inside parts, match the inner color of characters with the current background'. (And as you might know, it's a lot worse pain to make it look hollow since I need to work on masking and stuff. But I'd stick to the color matching method to keep it simple)

I look through youtube for the right way or even a trick, but I haven't found one.
Now I am starting to think if GP is really ready for 2d animation as people insist. Text could be a big part in animation depending on jenre, you know.

I just need to create a 3-minute-long animation with texts as simple and efficient as possible. So, here are my questions:

1. Can I see a text object's keyframes in dope sheet, by any means, so that I can manipulate all kinds of keyframes once and for all?
   (I tried 'set parent' and stuff but I failed.)
2. What would be your best practice if you need to work with lots of text in GP?
3. If there is no better choice than my attempts above, is GP team working on some feature improvements? Because they seem to need it.

[image]